# Laravel hasManyThrough joining on wrong ID

Tags: laravel, has-many-through

I have a relation

```
   public function followers(){
           return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User','App\Follow','owner_id','follower_id);
   }
```

Its not working though.  It says...

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;users.follower_id&#039; in &#039;on clause&#039;
```

Which is obvious.  Because it should be joining on the ID on the users table.
But if I change it to

```
public function followers(){
       return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User','App\Follow','owner_id','id);
```

}

It returns a collection, but its joining the user ID, with the App\Follow ID.
So its returning user #1.  Connected to App\Follow #1.

I want it to be returning user #42  Connected to App\Follow #1.  (follower_id is 42 in this example)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Provide more context, like DB design; because it looks like you could use a regular hasMany

Comment: I cant use a regular hasMany because its a pivot.  Theres a follow table.  Which contains ID's of the followers, which need to be linked up to the current user.   So a user has many follows, and all those follows have users which I need to access.  Ive sorted it with a join query, just wanted to do it using eloquent, but meh.  Its done now and works with regular old fluent join

Comment: If you post the three tables design I'm sure we could figure out the way to do it with Eloquent, at least it could be educational for others landing in this question. And also, using a join query makes you deal with soft delete(if you have that) manually, while Eloquent will take that responsebility out of you